# ngShow takes focus from input on mobile Safari

Tags: angularjs, focus, mobile-safari, ng-show

I want to toggle visibility of a div every time an input element is clicked. I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-click="show = !show"/>   
<div ng-show="show">Im visible</div>
```

In mobile Safari (iPad) the input loses focus when the div is shown. As a result it is not possible to enter text in the input. Sometimes the keyboard pops halfway up, but goes back down.

I have tried to focus the input again, by calling a focus function every time the div is turned visible. Below is the directive code (simplified):

```
app.directive('myDir', function(){
    return{
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            scope.focus = function(){
                setTimeout(function() {
                    element.find('input').eq(0)[0].focus();
                }, 500);
            }
        },
        template: '<input type="text" ng-click="toggle()"/>' +   
                  '<div ng-show="show">Im visible</div>',
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.toggle = function(){
                $scope.show = !$scope.show;
                if($scope.show) $scope.focus();
            };
        }
    };
};
```

This puts focus on the input, but the keyboard does not show up, so it is still quite useless.

It works fine on Android devices and desktops.

Does anyone know how to solve/get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I created a plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/lqrtCO8KuPtA3Cge8Qxr for the directive.
Everything seems to be working fine in iOS8 once I made a few changes to the directive (wrapping the template in a containing div and converting setTimeout to angular's $timeout)

```
app.directive('myDir', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, element, attr){
        scope.focus = function(){
            $timeout(function() {
                element.find('input').eq(0)[0].focus();
            });
        }
    },
    template: '<div><input type="text" ng-click="toggle()"/>' +   
              '<div ng-show="show">Im visible</div></div>',
    controller: function($scope){
        $scope.toggle = function(){
            $scope.show = !$scope.show;
            if($scope.show) {
              $scope.focus();
            }
        };
    }
  };
}]);
```

Everything else should be in working order, though I have heard iOS struggles with focusing on inputs not handled by a "click" handler. However, your directive clicks the input directly!